# Each javascript after return ajax array

Tags: javascript

My function javascript

```
setInterval(function(){
    jQuery.post("item.php?ac=show",
    {}, function(data)
    {
        $.each(data, function(index, value) {
           console.log(value);
        });
    }); 
}, 10000);
```

My return php

```
Array
(
  [10] => Pago
  [12] => Pago
)
```

I need to read the array that comes from php in javascript through each

Comment: I have no clue what you are asking.

Comment: That output is how PHP stringifies arrays, it's not something Javsscript can understand. You need to use `json_encode` in the PHP script to return your data in JSON format, then set the jQuery ajax option that says you're expecting JSON as a response.

Comment: Can you also add the snippet of code that streams back the Array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  function getData() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "item.php?ac=show",
            type: "get",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                    console.log(value);
                });

            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }

    setInterval(getData, 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
url: "item.php?ac=show",
success: function (response){
$.each(function (key, value){
console.log(value);
}):
}
});
```

Check out this code will solve your query.